# R: Compilation error "ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member" when installing feather package

Tags: c++, r, package, rstudio, feather

I'm using R version 3.1.2 and want to install the "feather" package in RStudio:

```
install.packages("feather", type="source")
```

Using a source version because there doesn't seem to be a binary version.
It does extract the file and checks for MD5 sums correctly, but throws errors for several sub-steps:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'xy'
```

Here's an extract of what exactly RStudio tells me:

> from c:\users...\r\win-library\3.1\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/algorithm:63,
>                    from ./feather/buffer.h:18,
>                    from ./feather/metadata.h:23,
>                    from ./feather/reader.h:21,
>                    from feather/feather-c.cc:21:
>   c:\users...\r\win-library\3.1\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/limits:196:57: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'is_specialized'
>   c:\users...\r\win-library\3.1\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/limits:201:48: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'digits'
>   c:\users...\r\win-library\3.1\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/limits:204:50: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'digits10'
>   
> ...(for many other parts)...
>   (also for some:)
>   c:\users...\r\win-library\3.1\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/limits:1587:58: note: 'bool std::numeric_limits::has_quiet_NaN' is not const
>   (and:)
>   c:\users...\r\win-library\3.1\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/limits:1607:51: error: the value of 'std::numeric_limits::has_infinity' is not usable in a constant expression
>   (then some:)
>   c:\users...\r\win-library\3.1\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/random.tcc:345:7: error: '_M_x' was not declared in this scope
>   (and finally:)
>   confused by earlier errors, bailing out
>   make: *** [feather/feather-c.o] Error 1
>   Warnung: Ausführung von Kommando 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" CXX='$(CXX1X) $(CXX1XSTD)' CXXFLAGS='$(CXX1XFLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX1XPICFLAGS)' SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLD)' SHLIB="feather.dll" OBJECTS="RcppExports.o feather-read.o feather-types.o feather-write.o"' ergab Status 2
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package 'feather'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/.../R/win-library/3.1/feather'
>   * restoring previous 'C:/Users/.../R/win-library/3.1/feather'
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users...\R\win-library\3.1" C:\Users...\AppData\LocalTemp\RtmpKsxa73/downloaded_packages/feather_0.3.2.tar.gz' had status 1
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘feather’ had non-zero exit status

I wanted to install the feather-package via CRAN. It doesn't work in RStudio, nor does it in the R console. Running this on Windows 8.1.

Anybody have an idea why this won't install?

To me the problem lies somewhere with the package?
Or could it be a problem with authorization (I do not have administrative rights with my user, but I can install anything in C:\Users\my_user)

Comment: Maybe it has been working with older compilers. You should contact the author of that package and ask them to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific language feature was [first supported in GCC 4.7](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11). You have GCC 4.6.3.

You will need to acquire a newer GCC or Clang installation.
If I read the error message correctly, you got your GCC from RTools 3.1. Looking at the [project page for Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), Rtools 3.3 and up default to GCC 4.9 and up, which should support the code used by your `feather` extension.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
If I get the Rtools page correctly, I'd have to update my R, too, right? Since Rtools 3.3 and up correspond to R 3.2 and up?

Comment: Updated R to R 3.4 and RTools to vesion 3.5 and finally got to install feather. Thank you very much!